# How is the string column in DataFrame split into multiple columns when Spark Structed Streaming

Tags: pyspark

This is the current code:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

park_session = SparkSession\
    .builder\
    .appName("test")\
    .getOrCreate()

lines = spark_session\
    .readStream\
    .format("socket")\
    .option("host", "127.0.0.1")\
    .option("port", 9998)\
    .load()

The 'lines' looks like this:
+-------------+
|    value    |
+-------------+
|     a,b,c   |
+-------------+

But I want to look like this：
+---+---+---+
| a | b | c |
+---+---+---+
```

I tried using the 'split()' method, but it didn't work. You could only split each string into a list in a column, not into multiple columns

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`Split`** the value column and by accessing `array index` (or) `element_at(from spark-2.4)` (or) `getItem()` functions to [create new columns.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45971114/scala-spark-splitting-dataframe-column-dynamically)

---

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

lines.withColumn("tmp",split(col("value"),',')).\
withColumn("col1",col("tmp")[0]).\
withColumn("col2",col("tmp").getItem(1)).\
withColumn("col3",element_at(col("tmp"),3))
drop("tmp","value").\
show()
#+----+----+----+
#|col1|col2|col3|
#+----+----+----+
#|   a|   b|   c|
#+----+----+----+
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but what is 'col()' is method? I haven't used it. I'm sorry;I haven't been around long

Comment: @NickWick, `col()` is used to access column from dataframe.. i.e `lines.value`,`lines["value"]`,`col("value")` all are referring to `value` column in pyspark.

Comment: Thanks for your careful explanation. I understand now

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark_session = SparkSession\
    .builder\
    .appName("test")\
    .getOrCreate()

lines = spark_session\
    .readStream\
    .format("socket")\
    .option("host", "127.0.0.1")\
    .option("port", 9998)\
    .load()

split_col = f.split(lines['value'], ",")
df = df.withColumn('col1', split_col.getItem(0))
df = df.withColumn('col2', split_col.getItem(1))
df = df.withColumn('col2', split_col.getItem(2))

df.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Incase you have different numbers of delimiters and not just 3 for each row , you can use the below:

**Input:**

```
+-------+
|value  |
+-------+
|a,b,c  |
|d,e,f,g|
+-------+
```

---

**Solution**

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

max_size = df.select(F.max(F.length(F.regexp_replace('value','[^,]','')))).first()[0]
out = df.select([F.split("value",',')[x].alias(f"Col{x+1}") for x in range(max_size+1)])
```

---

**Output**

```
out.show()

+----+----+----+----+
|Col1|Col2|Col3|Col4|
+----+----+----+----+
|   a|   b|   c|null|
|   d|   e|   f|   g|
+----+----+----+----+
```